# Get public key of tx that currently in txpool

Tags: rpc, monerod-commands, source, txpool, transaction-key

Can someone tell me how I can get list of public keys of the transactions, which are currently in the txpool and has not yet been mined? That is, I am interested in how to get this information out of the data returned, for example, by this rpc request:
https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_transaction_pool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction public key is contained in the txextra part of the get_transaction_pool response.

The format of txextra is documented here: https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns005.txt

You therefore want to parse txextra and look for subfield 0x01.

Please could you leave a comment and let us know how you made the tx private key deterministic? What are you hashing together to determine your tx private keys?

Comment: @Parean I don't know much about that bug, perhaps you can post another question about that. One important thing to point out is that when you send funds to multiple subaddresses, there needs to be a tx public key for each recipient. You'll see in the codebase that there is an additional_pubkeys tag for those extra ones. This is due to the way that subaddresses require the tx public key to be differently constructed than for transactions to regular addresses

Comment: @Parean yes. Also note that when you send to any subaddress (even if it's the only destination), the txpubkey is calculated as `r*publicspendkey` instead of `r*basepointG`, because sending to subaddresses works differently than regular addresses.